# xmpp - jabber offline message are not receiving while wifi is unreachable

Tags: ios, xmpp, offline, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am not getting the offline messages when my device is unreachable

but getting the offline messages send while i kill the app in iPhone.
 But my issue is i am not getting the offline messages when my wifi connection lost.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add message reliability, you need to support acknoledgement and stream management in your client. Please look at XEP-0198: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html